# Using SIMD video instructions in inline ptx assembly CUDA

Tags: assembly, cuda, simd, ptx

I want to use the SIMD video instructions (vadd4, vmax4 etc.)
Section 8.7.13 in http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/ptx_isa_3.1.pdf

I tried the following in my code

```
asm("vadd4.u32.u32.u32 %0, %1, %2, %3;" : "=r"(i) : "r"(j) : "r"(k) : "r"(l));
```

where i,j,k,l are int variables. I used "r", as it is the constraint for .u32 reg

But on compiling, I get the following error

> error: unknown register name "r"

What should I use instead of "r" here? Or is there something else wrong in the code?
(I am using a Tesla card with compute capability 3.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have a slight syntax error.  Try this:

```
asm("vadd4.u32.u32.u32 %0, %1, %2, %3;" : "=r"(i) : "r"(j) , "r"(k) , "r"(l));

                                                           ^        ^
                                                           |        |
Note the replacement of two of your colons (:) with commas (,)
```

You may wish to refer to the following document:

```
/usr/local/cuda/doc/pdf/Using_Inline_PTX_Assembly_In_CUDA.pdf
```

(assuming a standard cuda 5 linux install; just use your file search function if on a windows machine)

On page 4 of that document it states:

> ...you can have multiple input or output operands separated by commas.

Comment: You can find examples for the use of the SIMD video instructions via inline PTX in a header file of wrapper functions that NVIDIA makes available to registered developers: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/535684/announcements/release-1-1-of-simd-in-a-word-functions-posted/